# Issue about make a new challenge on Google reCAPTCHA via Selenium in VBA EXCEL?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

Follow the picture, I need to click on the new challenge via Selenium in Excel VBA.

[image]

Bellow is my code in VBA Excel:

```
Option Explicit
Public driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Public Sub reCAPTCHAClicker()
    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    driver.Start
    driver.Window.Maximize
    driver.Get " " 'The website I am trying to work on it.
    driver.SwitchToFrame (0) 'To go inside the iframe of the reCAPTCHA.
    driver.FindElementByClass("recaptcha-checkbox-border").Click 'Click on the checkbox of reCAPTCHA.
    driver.wait (3000) 'Wait until picture selecting appears.
    DoEvents
    driver.SwitchToFrame (0) 'To go inside the iframe of the picture selecting.
    DoEvents
    driver.wait (3000) 'Wait because the system does not recognize me as robot.
    driver.FindElementById("recaptcha-reload-button").Click
```

So as you see I tried by ID at the last line. but it says:

[image]

Then I changed the last line by its class:

```
driver.FindElementByClass("rc-button goog-inline-block rc-button-reload").Click
```

but it says:

[image]

After that I tried by its upper class. So I changed last line to this:

```
driver.FindElementByClass("button-holder reload-button-holder").Click
```

but it says again:

[image]

So I got confused!!!
Could you please help me on this?

Also please see this picture, which is the inspect of the new challenge button:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
Option Explicit
Public driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Public Sub reCAPTCHAClicker()
    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    driver.Start
    driver.Window.Maximize
    driver.Get " " 'The website I am trying to work on it.
    driver.SwitchToFrame (0) 'To go inside the iframe of the reCAPTCHA.
    driver.FindElementByClass("recaptcha-checkbox-border").Click 'Click on the checkbox of reCAPTCHA.
    driver.wait (3000) 'Wait until picture selecting appears.
    DoEvents
    driver.SwitchToDefaultContent 'To get back outside from iframe(0)
    driver.SwitchToFrame (2) 'To go inside the iframe of the picture selecting.
    DoEvents
    driver.wait (3000) 'Wait because the system does not recognize me as robot.
    driver.FindElementById("recaptcha-reload-button").Click
    driver.SwitchToDefaultContent 'To get back outside from iframe(2)
End Sub
```